# Visual Studio Code Remote Python Debug on Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to remotely develop and debug Python code on another PC on the same network (both Windows 10)?  If so, what is the best way to do this?

I tried mapping a network drive to the project folder on the remote PC.  I could open the folder in vs code, but cannot get it to start my virtual environment on the remote machine to start debugging.  When I do "Select Python Interpreter" and choose the appropriate venv on the remote machine it does nothing.  The same process works fine if the venv is installed on the development machine.

I normally use WSL remote for C++ development and it works great but cant find any documentation for remote Windows development, just WSL, docker and SSH (maybe an option?)

Advice appreciated.  Thanks in advance...

Comment: I guess you want [Remote script debugging with SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-script-debugging-with-ssh). Please follow the tutorial and have a try.

Comment: Molly Wang thanks for your suggestion.  I thought that may be the only way.  I was hoping there was something built in that just works without configuration at both ends like the WSL remote does.

Comment: Some negatives of the remote SSH option are that it appears you need to launch the application on the remote computer manually each time you want to debug (as you are effectively attaching to a running process).  Also these comments from the above mentioned page "On this toolbar, the disconnect button (Shift+F5) stops the debugger and allows the remote program to run to completion. The restart button (Ctrl+Shift+F5) restarts the debugger on the local computer but does not restart the remote program"

Comment: Umm. I'm afraid it couldn't be achieved. I'll do some research and if any update, i'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't want you to waste time on it for my sake.  I just wheeled the PC over to my desk and work on it directly.  In the future I will probably just use some sort of remote desktop program.

Comment: Okay, happy coding

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73378057/11107541