# How to debug remote Python script in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I am doing Python development in Raspberry Pi. I have installed VS Code in my laptop and have installed the `ssh` extension. Using this I can easily connect to Raspberry Pi. While I am connected I can see that VS Code has also loaded the Python interpreter of Raspberry Pi. I can run my Python script from within the vs code but when I tried to debug the code, nothing happens.

Is it possible to remotely debug the Python script from laptop to Raspberry Pi? How can I enable this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. If anyone wants to do remote development and **debugging**, follow below steps:

1. Install remote ssh extension in VS code
2. Once installed, you will find a green icon on the bottom left corner in vs code which allows us to connect to the remote machine.
3. Connect to the remote machine using the standard ssh command. Alternatively, you can use ssh-keygen to generate a public-private key if you don't want to use the password at every prompt.
4. Once you are connected to remote machine, you can open the file explorer and create any python file. When you will save this, it will get saved in your remote machine. This way you are using your machine to remotely develop code on another remote machine.
5. Good thing about vs code is that it selects the remote machine's python interpreter so all the packages which you have installed on your remote machine will work with IntelliSense.
6. In order to debug the code, we will use [debugpy](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy). Install this on both machine (remote & local)
7. On your remote machine, run below command:

`python3 -m debugpy --listen 1.2.3.4:5678 --wait-for-client app.py`

here `1.2.3.4` is the IP of remote machine. This will start a remote debugger which will wait for a clients connection.

8. On your local machine, in VS code open Run & Debug, add a configuration of `Python: Remote Attach`. Make sure that `launch.json` has the host as the IP of your remote machine and port as 5678.
9. Now start debugging as normal and you will notice the code will break at first breakpoint and from here you can proceed normally as we used to do in local debugging process.

TBH, this is best feature VS code has because most of the software allows you to do remote development which is nothing but just a normal SSH but remote debugging gives you more control. I was doing some python project on `Raspberry Pi` and obviously cannot install VS code or pycharm on it. But with this feature now I can easily develop the code using Pi's python interpreter and debug it as well.

If anyone is having any issues, let me know. Happy to help.

Comment: Note that this solution requires you to open up port 5678 on host 1.2.3.4. If host 1.2.3.4 is a public facing internet host  this introduces a serious security risk (or attack vector as the cool kids say). It is safer to use host localhost and (for example) port 8888 and use SSH port forwarding by adding a line like:

LocalForward 8888  localhost:8888

in your ~/.ssh/config file.

Comment: I don't think localhost will work here. Localhost will connect to the machine where vscode is running while we want to connect to the machine where debugpy is running and the IP doesn't have to be a public IP, infact all of this work can be done offline without internet.

Comment: My comment mentions 'localhost' in the context of SSH port forwarding. It assumes you already have an SSH connection to the remote host where the process you want to debug is running. And it does work, i am using it myself.

Comment: @Jan and are you able to remotely debug your python scripts using this ?

Comment: Yes i am. I will put the details in a seperate answer so i can use code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

This is an addition to the answer by S Andrew on this page. Remote Python debugging in Visual Studio Code is most securely done using SSH Port Forwarding. Add the following snippet to your .ssh/config file:

```
Host remote
     HostName remote.host.org
     User jan
     Port 1234
     LocalForward 1238 localhost:1239
```

Ssh into your remote host and run the program to debug as follows:

```
~local  > ssh remote
~remote > python3 -m debugpy --listen localhost:1239 --wait-for-client app.py
```

Inside Visual studio code, create a Remote Run/Debug Configuration that listens to the port localhost:1238.

Your debugging bits will flow through your SSH tunnel and the only port open on your remote host is 1234.

Answer (score 1):

To highly simplify the remote debugging process between two windows machines, make is universal for all IDEs and avoid SSH file permission errors on Windows, I made my own python library that solves this problem.

Just run `pip install pywinrd` and create those two scripts:-

Server.py

```
from PyWinRD.Server import WinRDServer

server = WinRDServer()
server.start()
```

Client.py

```
from PyWinRD.Client import WinRDClient

client = WinRDClient()
client.connect()

client.deploy('path/to/file/or/folder')
client.debug('path/to/python/script')
client.terminal('termninal command')

client.disconnect()
```

Run `Server.py` on the host Windows machine, and `Client.py` on your machine, you will have the ability to execute terminal commands, deploy extra files/folders and debug any python script you want on the host machine.

A copy of all the stdout, stderr calls on the python script you are debugging will be redirected to your machine in real-time (ex. print and raise statements).

All the stdin calls will be redirected to your machine only (ex. input statements), so the server will not interfere with them.