# Can VSCode attach to a remote Python process and debug locally?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I have a .par file built from python scripts, and it runs on a remote machine. I have the source codes on my local machine. Is it possible for me to attach my local python codes to the process running on the remote machine, and do the debugging using break points, steps, etc?

I know Visual studio has similar features for c# program debugging, but not sure whether VScode can do the same thing for Python scripts.

Comment: You can refer to [official document with details](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_debugging-by-attaching-over-a-network-connection).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug remote Python script in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73378057/how-to-debug-remote-python-script-in-vs-code)

Comment: Thanks @rustyhu and starball, I read both the articles. Just not sure whether they would work for me. I'm trying out the methods in the, will post my results if I get it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [ptvsd package](https://pypi.org/project/ptvsd/).

1. Install the ptvsd package on the remote machine by running the
   following command in a terminal: `pip install ptvsd`
2. In your Python code on the remote machine, add the following lines of code to enable remote debugging:

```py
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('0.0.0.0', 5678))
```

This will start the ptvsd debugger and listen for incoming connections on port 5678.

4. Start your Python process on the remote machine.
5. In VS Code on your local machine, set the "host" and "port" properties to the IP address and port of the remote machine in the `launch.json`. You can refer to the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-script-debugging-with-ssh) for more details.